# Why isn't my pagination code working?

Tags: php, pagination

I have this pagination code and the `&pagenum=whatever` is showing up perfectly fine in my URL but it just does absolutely nothing and I really don't know why.  Here is my code:

paginate.php:

```
 <?php

include("config.php"); 

 if (!(isset($pagenum))) 

 { 

 $pagenum = 1; 

 } 

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shop
    WHERE MATCH (name,description,keywords) AGAINST ('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)") or die(mysql_error()); 

 $rows = mysql_num_rows($data);  

 $page_rows = 5; 

 $last = ceil($rows/$page_rows); 

 if ($pagenum < 1) 

 { 

 $pagenum = 1; 

 } 

 elseif ($pagenum > $last) 

 { 

 $pagenum = $last; 

 } 

 $max = 'limit ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows; 

 ?>
```

search.php:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['result']);
?>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="searchleft">
</div>
<div class="search">
<center>
<form method="get" action="search.php">
<input type="text" name="result" value="<?php echo $search; ?>" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<?php   
include("paginate.php");

$data_p = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shop
    WHERE MATCH (name,description,keywords) AGAINST ('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE) $max") or die(mysql_error());

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($data_p);

if ($num_rows == "1") {
    echo "Returned 1 result.";
} else { echo "Returned ".$num_rows." results."; }

while ($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($data_p)) {
    $name = stripslashes($info['name']);
    $desc = stripslashes($info['description']);
    $desc = substr($desc, 0, 150);
    $price = stripslashes($info['price']);
    Print "<div style=\"width:600px; height:150px; border:1px solid black; overflow:hidden\"><div style=\"height:148px; width:25%; border:1px solid red; float:left\"><center><img src=\"".$picture."\" height=\"120\" width=\"120\" style=\"margin-top:15px\" /></center></div><div style=\"height:150px; width:50%; border:1px solid blue; float:left; text-overflow: ellipsis; padding-top:5px\"><center><font size=\"+1\"><b><a href=\"result.php?product=".urlencode($name)."\">".$name."</b></a></font><br><br>".$desc."...</center></div><div style=\"height:150px; width:24%; border:1px solid green; float:left\"><center><h1>$".$price."</h1><button>Add to Cart</button></center></div></div>";
}
echo " --Page $pagenum of $last-- <p>";
 if ($pagenum == 1) 
 {

 } 

 else 

 {
 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?result=".$search."&pagenum=1'> First</a> ";
 $previous = $pagenum-1;
 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?result=".$search."&pagenum=$previous'>Previous</a> ";

 }  
  if ($pagenum == $last) 
 {
 } 
 else {
 $next = $pagenum+1;
 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?result=".$search."&pagenum=$next'>Next</a> ";

 echo " ";

 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?result=".$search."&pagenum=$last'>Last</a> ";

 } 

 ?>
```

I'm honestly stumped.

Comment: Where is `$pagenum` set?

Comment: The top of paginate.php I suppose.  If it isnt set, it's set to 1.  If it's already set, it's whatever it's set to

Comment: You probably want `$_GET['pagenum']` instead.

Comment: Well the &pagenum=whatever does work perfectly fine as is, its just that it doesn't do anything to the page

Comment: Yes, and to access the variable in the URL you need to use `$_GET`, just like you do with `$search` on the top of the other file.

Comment: where do I need $_GET, in search.php or paginate.php?

Comment: I can't see any actual pagination in the query. Normally, there is a `LIMIT` statement that does this at the database level ("get X rows starting from row Y").

Comment: at the bottom of paginate.php, there is a "$max" with the LIMIT statement in it and it's used in my query in search.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at the comments, instead of

```
if (!(isset($pagenum))) 
{ 
  $pagenum = 1; 
}
```

you need this:

```
if (!(isset($_GET['pagenum']))) {     
  $pagenum = 1;   
} else {
  $pagenum = $_GET['pagenum'];
}

// or with a ternary line
$pagenum = (isset($_GET['pagenum'])) ? $_GET['pagenum'] : 1;
```

also this part of your code is doing an expensive database call:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shop WHERE MATCH (name,description,keywords) AGAINST ('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)") or die(mysql_error()); 
$rows = mysql_num_rows($data);
```

do a count instead of fetching the entire table:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM shop WHERE MATCH (name,description,keywords) AGAINST ('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)") or die(mysql_error()); 
$result = mysql_fetch_array($data, MYSQL_NUM);
$rows = $result[0];
```

Comment: That worked wonderfully.  Small question now...say I have 11 entries which would yield three pages.  Is there a simple way I can make a dropdown list that says Jump to page: and then the dropdown list has 1, 2 and 3 as options or however many pages there are?